# Ошибки в коде при использовании Webpack указывают только на файл bundle.js

Tags: webpack

Почему когда я допускаю ошибки, Webpack не указывает в каком файле проблема, а указывает только на bundle.js?

Версия Webpack 3.8.1 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить sourcemap чтобы браузер понимал какая строка из бандла относится к какому файлу. Сделать это можно указав в настройках webpack `devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map'`. Подробнее в [доках](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)